# update fields based on table to table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I am in brain stroming situation. I thought, lets explain to geeks, So they can help me to resolve this problem.

I have table called Sharepoint_Users in Oracle. (see below format and data). I have access oracle db from linked server.Don't worry about it. Just consider it is sql table.

```
SharePoint_Users

ID         Status
1           Active
2           InActive
3           Active
4           InActive
```

another two tables called aspnet_user and aspnet_UsersInRoles in SQL server.

```
aspnet_users
UserID                                       UserName      

A7DFDDAE-4DB8-476D-9C29-677763406F71          1
D9910E14-9206-4460-88CA-4C39DE620192          2
F188B1DF-03A6-4332-BA89-3B3C6682E9BA          3
728E77E7-693A-4015-92CA-02F0A403C29A          4

asnet_usersInRoles

UserID                                      RoleID

A7DFDDAE-4DB8-476D-9C29-677763406F71        1E36A840-2EBB-44EC-8861-0E3D262AC676 ----> InActive
D9910E14-9206-4460-88CA-4C39DE620192        0B54F223-E0D4-4CFC-84C3-7C98C1BFC6DA --->Active
```

Now here is the challenge.

```
* When users status changes in SharePoint_Users table from 'Active' to 'InActive'
 OR 'InActive' to 'Active'. We need to update same users RoleID in 
 asnet_usersInRoles table.


* And also I need insert new records those not exists in asnet_usersInRoles 
  table but exists in aspnet_users table.
  If user not found in aspnet_users should not insert them into 
  asnet_usersInRoles.(always users will be the same SharePoint_Users 
  and aspnet_users)
```

Please help me out write a sp to get it done. I will run job for this sp every 1 hr to update.

Comment: Nerd, fine, but geek? How dare you sir! ;)

Comment: We don't delete questions because you wish to freshen it up.  Please think of a different way to do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to update when SharePoint_Users changes I guess you need a trigger but you also write that you will run the SP every 1 hr so...

Anyway here is an insert statement for your second part and an update statement for the first part. Since you do not know what rows have been changed the update updates all rows.

```
insert into asnet_usersInRoles(UserID, RoleID)
select
  UserID,
  case s.[Status] when 'Active'
    then '0B54F223-E0D4-4CFC-84C3-7C98C1BFC6DA'
    else '1E36A840-2EBB-44EC-8861-0E3D262AC676'
  end
from aspnet_users as au
  inner join (select ID, min([Status]) as [Status]
              from SharePoint_Users
              group by ID) as s
    on au.UserName = s.ID
where not exists (select *
                  from asnet_usersInRoles as uir
                  where au.UserID = uir.UserID)

update asnet_usersInRoles
set RoleID = case s.[Status] when 'Active'
               then '0B54F223-E0D4-4CFC-84C3-7C98C1BFC6DA'
               else '1E36A840-2EBB-44EC-8861-0E3D262AC676'
             end
from asnet_usersInRoles as uir
  inner join aspnet_users as u
    on uir.UserID = u.UserID
  inner join (select ID, min([Status]) as [Status]
              from SharePoint_Users
              group by ID) as s
    on u.UserName = s.ID
```

Comment: @James123. Updated answer to what I believe you are after. The new guids represent Active and Inactive?

Comment: Thats true. new guids represents Active and InActive only. Let me try this in local machine and then apply on prod. Thanks for you help.

Comment: Mikael, I have question here. 'SharePoint_Use' table has some duplate records. around 200 users has both 'Active' and 'InActive' Can we handle them here in this query?

Comment: @James123 Yes if you have a way of deciding what duplicate to use. For example, always pick Active before Inactive or if you have a date/timestamp column always use the latest registered.

Comment: @Mikael, Yes, I want to always 'Active' before 'Inactive' only. No date and time stamp. Can you make change, please?

Comment: @James123 Used a sub-query and `min(Status)` to get active before inactive.

Answer (score 0):

When you want something to modify data in a table when another table is updated, use a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER SharePoint_Users_Trg_Upd ON SharePoint_Users
AFTER UPDATE
AS
/* update statements here */
GO
```

This way you don't need the sp to listen every hour.

Comment: What would be the performance ramifications of having a trigger on an Oracle table, that updates tables on a SQL Server?